# Changing NSUserDefaults class properties after save (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, updating, saving-data

Say I have a custom object defined as such:

```
class Person {
  firstName:String,
  lastName:String,
  age:Int
}
```

After releasing an app version, say I wanted to add a `gender:String` property. How would I do this even though the current class does not contain the gender property?

Comment: why not define it as a struct?

Comment: I don't care whether it gets defined as struct, class, or enum. I just want to know how you can edit the existing nsuserdefaults properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it in future releases of the app.
First, update your Person class, then you can set a value `versionOfLastRun`and check if it's nil. In this case you check if there is already a Person saved in NSUserDefaults and if it's so you create a new instance of your class to save in *NSUserDefaults*, with the gender and you overwrite the previous Person object.

```
let currentVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
let versionOfLastRun = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "VersionOfLastRun") as? String

if versionOfLastRun == nil {
    if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Person") as? Person) != nil {
        let newPerson = Person( //... )
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentVersion, forKey: "Person")
    } else {
        print("First run")
    }
} else if !(versionOfLastRun! == currentVersion)  {
    print("App updated")

    // Upgrade your model

} else {
    print("Nothing changed since last run")
}

UserDefaults.standard.set(currentVersion, forKey: "VersionOfLastRun")
```

In next releases of the app, if you want to upgrade your data model you do this by checking the version of last run.

Hope this answers to your question.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks